# Why am I getting the error Value of type 'UIImageView' has no member 'sd_setShowActivityIndicatorView'

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore, sdwebimage

I am trying to show a loader while my images are being downloaded using the SDWebImage library. [The wiki page](https://github.com/SDWebImage/SDWebImage/wiki/Common-Problems) says it should be done like so:

```
imageView.sd_setShowActivityIndicatorView(true)
```

However when I put it in my code:

```
cell.firstImageView.sd_setShowActivityIndicatorView(true)
```

I get the error:

```
Value of type 'UIImageView' has no member 'sd_setShowActivityIndicatorView'
```

I have checked that the pod file is properly installed with `pod SDWebImage`, and I know it is working because my images load when I call `sd_set_Image()`

Answer (score 0):

Swift 5 removed `sd_setShowActivityIndicatorView` from the pod `SDWebImage`, but we can use `sd_imageIndicator` instead. So, for example:

```
cell.firstImageView.sd_imageIndicator = SDWebImageActivityIndicator.gray

cell.firstImageView.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: urlString), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "loading"))
```